# Is there any way one can be a Monk without a teacher in India/Nepal?

Tags: meditation

Nowadays, it can be seen that instead of doing meditation people are focusing on rectifying outside world. Some of such people call themselves a saint, sanyaasi, monk, swami, mahaguru (great teacher), sadguru(teacher of all), etc.

But it can be easily detected that they are not worthy of such noble words. If someone is unsatisfied in one way or other and is not ready to compromise in any way, can that person be a "self inspired meditator" to be an Arahant?

Remember Buddha's last words: "Atta Hi Attano Natho" (You are your own master), in fact this is what our mind does.

Is it possible to live an ascetic life in India/Nepal and meditate to one's heart's contents?

Any suggestions of such place in India/Nepal? (That place must be silent, as in pin-drop-silence).

This question has 2 parts:

1) Possibility of being a SELF - Meditator/Bhikkhu.

2) Silent place/ashram/Monastery in India/Nepal to practice Self-Meditation by being a monk without teacher, other than core teachings of Buddha (Means without teacher-student criteria)?

Contact me at tempoit1@gmail.com to have discussion/advice in private (if you don't want to answer in public).

Answer (score 1):

> Remember buddha's last words :: Atto Na Attanno Natho ~ You are your own teacher, infact this is what our Mind does.

It's important to see the Buddha's full paragraph because one cannot solely and entirely be one's own teacher without His Teaching:

> Therefore, Ānanda, live with yourself as an island, yourself as a refuge, with no other refuge, ***with the Teaching as an island, the Teaching as a refuge***, with no other refuge. And how, Ānanda, does a monk live with himself as an island, himself as a refuge, with no other refuge, with the Teaching as an island, the Teaching as a refuge, with no other refuge?
>
> Here, Ānanda, a monk dwells contemplating the nature of the body in the body, ardent, fully aware, and mindful, after removing avarice and sorrow regarding the world; he dwells contemplating the nature of feelings in feelings, ardent, fully aware, and mindful, after removing avarice and sorrow regarding the world; he dwells contemplating the nature of the mind in the mind, ardent, fully aware, and mindful, after removing avarice and sorrow regarding the world; he dwells contemplating the nature of things in various things, ardent, fully aware, and mindful, after removing avarice and sorrow regarding the world... ~~ [DN 16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/anandajoti) ~~

So while it'd be helpful to have a knowledgeable and virtuous teacher who can coach/advise/correct you along your path, but if you're not able to find one who's truly knowledgeable and truly virtuous, it's totally legit. to go solo provided that you remember to cultivate the Path in both theory and in practice. Use great online resources like accesstoinsight.org, suttacentral.net, themindingcentre.org for the theoretical aspect and observe precepts/practice meditation for the practice side. Remember, one is a monk not because he shaves his head, wears an orange robe, and stays inside a monastery, but because he observes the Vinaya with its 227 rules and seriously cultivate Samadhi and Panna, just like you can't call someone a martial artist because he wears a gi and a black belt, but because you see him walking out of the ring alive and on his own two feet.

Comment: Yup! I know that . That's why at last ,in question, I wrote ," to practice Self-Meditation by being a Monk without teacher other than Core Teachings of Buddha". Also , it can be noticed that ," Atto Na Attanno Natho" in itself is complete as ,even if one is a student of Supreme teacher like buddha , s/he will only learn when s/he wants to -- here also one part of s/he Mind teaches another part . That's why ,Mind is it's own Master ,No-one else. Thanks for resource websites.

Answer (score 0):

No need any teacher
Don't become anything.(Monk,etc)
Only need awareness. Choiceless awareness .find out
What is awareness?
What is choiceless awareness?
Indian monk making money from faith.
Indian monk is fake.
Monk  making money  our ignorance .
Search " Ram Rahim ", nimal baba  " indian fake monk
Indian any monk making money from our ignorance..
I am indian so i knew it.

Comment: Fake monks :: can be anyone ,not restricted to India. Choiceless Awareness :: It's a type of behaviour that can either be done/applied by enlightened one or by residing alongside enlightened one. For others ,meditation is needed.

Comment: Choiceless awareness:: "what is " you are greedy. Aware  you are greedy. You are feeling hate. Aware you are hate feeling.  Don't  resistance

Comment: Question is not about type of awareness. It's about possibility of practicing self-meditation & asceticness(monkhoodness) in India/Nepal without any teacher.

Comment: No need any teacher

Comment: Silent Place(forest/mountain ashram/monastery) where such practice can be done by strictly maintaining 5 buddhist Percepts(Sheela) without anyone's disturbance ??

Comment: No need silent place. Only need mindfulness  or awareness.  Aware these moment. Awareness great meditation

Comment: Hmm, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in this topic but i can't answer based on texts nor give locations.

I can say that it seems to me that most gurus just want to get along and not step on eachothers toes. I've see this play out in public and in personal interaction. This benefits everyone involved in that it avoids conflict.

If you are self learned, capable of thinking, reading and writing people might see you as an op sec threat for this whole arrangement more so than a random person coming to learn enlightenments.

Therefore if you really want to be self-learned and autonomous then don't expect to be popular and enjoying the vast support of established structures neither from the yogis nor buddhists. I think there are these options id consider;
* ordain where people just don't care and do your own thing
* somehow get your own funding, a cave or some property 
* be homeless, pick bottles, scrap metal or whatnot

I think more and more people will find themselves in these circumstances and it is probably going to be quite difficult to build these places and even harder to maintain as a place conducive to legit growth. Thus they will probably not be a free for all and those same elements of op sec will come into play hopefully based on right views and not weakness & insecurity. It will essentially be perceived as just another Buddhist sect or an organization.

Comment: Agree with you in a lot of context .Ordain where no-one cares :: Correct. Get your own funding :: FALSE .Be Homeless :: Correct. Funding is not required , funding increases EGO. Cave is of nature & for everyone ,so no right of occupying cave otherwise it would not be homelessness .I know few such places but people from other sect residing there beacomes greatest distraction.

Comment: Monks are allowed to live in a cave or under a cliff, latter is considered a dhutanga. If you think you can do without then power to you but talk is cheap.

Comment: Oh! I never said that I wanna/going to do this. Also , What I meant was :: One can live in cave or under a cliff but can never be owner or claimer of that cave/cliff through an organization or by self.

Comment: In the mahavagga Ven Pilindavakkha has a cave cleared out to make a dwelling place ie https://books.google.no/books?id=1Uv8AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=vinaya+cave&source=bl&ots=SkptrjeQKr&sig=ACfU3U3asIbVMz4Bwdj2ZnJmpinO1s3LGQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN3YGjudPlAhWN0KYKHSdJDrkQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=vinaya%20cave&f=false

Comment: Ok i get it but for practical purposes you should make sure one legally occupies a dwelling. Not self argumentation doesn t work very well with law enforcement.

Comment: Hmm , thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Someone always teaches us. It could be from a book, from online videos or from Buddhist forum Q&A but I suppose you mean a one on one teacher that guides you in person.

It's possible to practice in harmony with a monk without a one on one teacher but a good teacher is likely to pinpoint certain subtle problems you are having far more effectively than a book generalized at a group of readers.

Monks aren't the only ones who can beg in a society although there are norms, traditions and beliefs between lay supporters and monks  that may  cause adversity for the ascetic that hasn't ordained but adversity handled wisely can be a teaching in itself.

Comment: Saint/Sanyasi/Mahatma/Mahapurush/Monk/Bhikkhu/Anagaami... are Noble words , not meant for anyone following any tradition. Hmm, Thanks for your ideology.

Comment: What do you mean? One doesn't have to follow any idea  nessasarily to become an anagami? People can enter stream entry and attain nirvana without ever hearing the ideas of the Buddha? I agree with that.

Comment: That's What India is famous for : Self-Enlightenment , even Gautama The Buddha was a Samyak Sambuddha , a Self-Enlightened one without any teacher. What I meant was ,"noble words aren't for just anyone following any belief/tradition without noble behaviour/karma ".

Comment: I'm sorry I am just trying to understand, Are you saying,  "noble words are meant for  noble behavior"? I am really confused at how  following beliefs and traditions fits in there.

Comment: Yup! Noble words like saint/Arhant  are meant for noble behaviour only.Even if person coming from any tradition/belief. Like Mahaveera Jain , Lord Buddha :: Both might had some different teaching method ,still same behaviour ;even their appearence(physical outlook) was same after they claimed enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Q1:
No need to move to India / Nepal. The place you are right now is the best place to start the journey. There are two things

1. Move to a forest, thinking it will help to focus
2. Move to forest or temple after realising that there's no meaning in this life. He moves to forest to increase the speed of getting enlightenment but not to run from the current life.

Majority of the people do the first thing, it's like driving in a play ground, which will cause many accidents when you drive it in the high way. So just to practice you may find a calm place, but running away from day to day life doesn't make sense.
Leaving the current life to a place where you can attend more on attaining Nibbana is the second point. But to do that you might first need to understand one thing. At least you must understand the problem of life.

So my advise is first find the correct dhamma. Don't try to follow a teacher. Keep in mind Dhamma is the only teacher. But today's dhamma is misinterpreted by many people who says that they are teachers. There are few in this forum as well.

With Metta..!

Answer (score 0):

If "it is easily detectable", then you must be able to know what's  wrong in their livelihood, in this case just try to live without doing those mistakes.

If by 'ascetic' you mean to live like how gautama lived after leaving both his teachers, then whichever country you are in whether india or nepal or whatever,  you don't  need to ask anyone cause wherever you are,  I hope your country would've  lot of villages,  forests,  mountains etc.

Pin-drop silent place is within, not outside.

Life is not so easy-going.  If you would've  been matured enough for independent meditation, you wouldn't  be here on internet asking strangers.

Sticking to questions only,  be matured enough to live alone and not to look back,  live like an old, weak man to ignore every distraction and remain focused on meditation, don't  look for food, clothes etc.

From Google maps,  India/Nepal is a vast land of forests,  mountains,  himalayas etc. If you are truely at a level of gautama,  don't  fear from this initial Mara which is pushing you to seek for a Silent&Helping place outside.